# javascript regex.exec match all the plain string and +-= symbol in it?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use a plain string as the regex expression parameter, and execute this regex against a string with some special symbol(+= ... etc) Here I have written a demo code, and a fiddle [here:](https://jsfiddle.net/matiascx/sa1sbgtx/2/)

```
var s = 'plain string plus some other symbol + other string '
var re = 'plain string plus some other symbol + '
var reg = new RegExp(re,'gu')
var myArray;
myArray = reg.exec(s)
console.log(myArray) // here does not work, return null
var s = 'plain string plus some other symbol and other string '
var re = 'plain string plus some other symbol and '
var reg = new RegExp(re,'gu')
var myArray;
myArray = reg.exec(s)
console.log(myArray) //here works: return 'plain string plus some other    symbol and '
```

How to make javascript regex.exec recognize the special symbol += as a plain string and match it?

Comment: Try `/\+\=/gm` (backslashes escape special chars)

Comment: thanks @Wiktor, in that thread, i found the solution with lodash escape function.